# Gettin Bad Access while adding Annotations

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I´m trying to to add many Annotations (depends on how many objects a have in my Array) to my Mapview like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];

for (Daten *info in datenArray) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = (double)[info.lati doubleValue];
    location.longitude = (double)[info.longi doubleValue];
    MapPin *newAnnotation =[[[MapPin alloc] initWithTitle:info.rating andCoordinate:location] autorelease];
    [mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
}

[self zoomToFitMapAnnotations:self.mapView];
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:self.mapView.annotations.lastObject animated:YES];
```

}

The first time I switch to that View it works perfectly...But if i come a second time to this View, i get this Bad Access with Error:

```
*** -[CFString length]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x17e140c0
```

Edit:

Thats my MapPin Class:

```
@interface MapPin : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

NSString *title;
NSString *subtitle;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *subtitle;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d;
```

EDIT2:

[image: Exception]

Edit3:

Here´s the implementation:

```
#import "MapPin.h"

@implementation MapPin
@synthesize title, coordinate, subtitle;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d {
[super init];
subtitle = ttl;
title = @"Rating:";
coordinate = c2d;
return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
[title release];
[subtitle release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: where do you use strings? Can you add more code? On which line your app crashes?

Comment: You are sending a wrong parameter somewhere :) I had a similar issue. You are sending a NSString where something else is expected (Like a class type or something).

Comment: Add an exception breackpoint, it will stop at the line causing the crash ;)

Comment: I already did...But it stop´s somewhere that´s not my Code...Updated my Question...

Comment: show initWithTitle: implementation, probably problem is there

Comment: what about implementation for this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send retain or copy message for object in init.

```
 if (self = [super init]) {
 subtitle = [ttl copy];
 title = [@"Rating:" retain]
 ...
 }
 return self;
```

`@"Rating:"` is equal method which create autoreleased object.

Or you can use `self.title = @"Rating:";`.

Comment: Perfect...Thanks for that! It is working now...But i don't really understand why it is working now...Can you explain it?!

Comment: You don't use Automatic Reference Counting and you should care about memory. I mean, you should retain/copy objects and release it then. You can read [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/articles/mmpractical.html) about it